# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'timeout'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I am trying to run some basic testcase for a basic project but I get this error in spite of initializing super class constructor. Below is my code.

home.py

```
class home(Pages):
    user = (By.NAME, "user-name")
    utxt = "standard_user"
    pwd = (By.ID, "password")
    ptxt = "secret_sauce"
    logbtn = (By.NAME, "login-button")
    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver=driver
        super().__init__(self.driver)
    def logg(self):
        pg=Pages(self.driver)
        pg.type(self.user,self.utxt)
        pg.type(self.pwd,self.ptxt)
        pg.click1(self.logbtn)`
```

GenricFun.py

```
class Pages:
    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver=driver

    def click1(self,locator):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver).until(e.visibility_of_element_located(locator)).click()

    def type(self,locator,txt):
       WebDriverWait(self.driver).until((e.visibility_of_element_located(locator))).send_keys(txt)`
```

Test_log.py

```
 class Test_log(TestBase):
    def test_log(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.saucedemo.com/")
        L=home(self.driver)
        L.logg()
```

`driver` in `test_log()` comes from fixtures method (confest.py)

Comment: Can you include the full traceback of the exception you're getting? Since your code is not a [mcve], I can't test it directly, and so I'm not sure I understand where exactly the error is coming from. None of your classes expects a `timeout` argument, so it's presumably one of the calls into library code, and it would help to know which one! On the topic of your classes, you're doing something deeply strange in `home.logg`, where you're creating another instance of your base class. You don't need to do that, just call those methods on `self`! You also don't need `home.__init__` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here

```
def click1(self,locator):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver).until(e.visibility_of_element_located(locator)).click()
```

You are missing parenthesis (), please use below code :

```
def click1(self,locator):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver).until((e.visibility_of_element_located(locator))).click()
```

**Update :**

The equivalent statement would be :

```
user = (By.NAME, "user-name")
WebDriverWait(driver).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(user)).click()
```

so the above defined method should be something like this :

```
def click1(self, locator):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator)).click()


def type(self, locator, txt):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator)).send_keys(txt)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I made your suggested chanages but it again showing same error for type () i thought it may be conflicting with type keyword in python so changes functions name to typt_txt and still i getting below error  on this line    `WebDriverWait(self.driver).until((e.visibility_of_element_located(locator))).send_keys(txt)`
 TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'timeout'

Comment: @shivani  : Check out the updated code above.

Comment: I'm very confused by this answer. The top part seems to put great emphasis on some parentheses that don't appear to me to do anything (they're redundant when not changing order of operations, like in `(1+2)`). I'm not sure I understand what the bottom half of the answer is saying. Can you edit again and try to make the answer a single coherent thing whole? We don't need to have the evolution of your thinking spelled out in the answer text, we can browse the edit history if we need to know that.